# easy way to create 4-6 character id of varchar format

Tags: php, url

I need to have a really simple way to make a shortened id that's always unique. For example, something is created and given a normal auto increment id. I need to have an alternative id if you will that's 4-6 characters.

something like a1b2 or abcd. they always need to be unique though. Please help if you can.

Comment: Do they always have to be printable characters? And how many items are you likely to need (10, 1000, 100,000)?

Comment: dangerously short for most usages.

Comment: @Dagon, Assuming case-insensitive letters and numbers, you can have 36^6 possible strings, for 2,176,782,336 entries.  That seems like plenty for most order id's or address tables; not for tracking twitter messages or network traffic packets, etc.

Comment: im paranoid, i start at 32 characters and go up

Comment: @Dagon, if end-users need to be able to type it (such as for an URL shortening site like goo.gl/bit.ly) or space conservation is important, then 5-6 characters is fine.  We don't know the requirements clearly, though.

Comment: @dagon i'd say in the millions to start off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
substr(str_shuffle(str_repeat('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789',5)),0,5);
```

The only way to test if its unique is to check against your database.  The possible space with only 4-6 char long strings is relatively small, collisions are quite likely.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$len = rand(3, 4); 
$hash = substr(str_shuffle("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"),0,$len);
```

Answer (score 0):

`uniqid()` has worked well for me (http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php). It returns a hex string that can be turned into a binary string of about 6-7 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Just hash the autoincrement id itself - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php and select the first 6 characters.

Comment: there's no guarantee that part of a hash, especially such a small part, will be unique even if the seed is, so will still have to check the db every time.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the insert id as its unique and pad it with 6x0's

```
<?php 
$value = sprintf("%06s",mysql_insert_id());
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write a function to convert the actual auto-generated ID into a base 36 number, represented by a-z and 0-9.   This would give 6-character strings up to 36^7 - 1 = 78,364,164,095 entries.  Note, however, that the database will skip some integer values for an autogenerated key (eg, with failed inserts, etc).

If you can be case sensitive, you can have 62^7 - 1 = 3,521,614,606,207 possible combinations.

There's source code for arbitrary base conversion, in PHP, at http://www.pgregg.com/projects/php/base_conversion/base_conversion.php?q=2309823&r=&qb=10&rb=60 -- although it's under an open source license.  Hopefully if you google around a bit you can find a Creative Commons or other appropriate license.  I suggest starting with "arbitrary base conversion php"

Answer (score 0):

you can use mysql conv() function on your auto increment primary key, to convert it from base 10 to, say, base 36. Or you can use [php base_convert](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base-convert.php)

in sql:

```
select yourId, conv(yourId, 10, 36) as shortId from yourTable
```

in php:

```
$shortId = base_convert($yourId, 10, 36);
```

[here](http://www.unitconversion.org/numbers/base-10-to-base-36-conversion.html) you can test what it would do exactly.

of course, it's completly unique, safe, and reversable (`$orignialId = base_convert($shortId, 36, 10)`, and both mysql and php versions are compatible, as they do exacty the same thing.

numerical auto increment field can go up to 1.6m before requiring 5 characters in base 36, and 60m before requiring 6.